# How to compare Mono error to a String in Java

Tags: java, junit, mono, assert

I have a method something like this :

```
public Mono<SomeDTO> DoAction(SomeDTO someDTOObject) {
        return findUser(someDTOObject.getUsername())
                .flatMap(existingUser -> {
                    Update update = new Update();
                   
                    return mongoTemplate.upsert(
                            Query.query(Criteria.where("username").is(someDTOObject.getUsername())),
                            update,
                            SomeDTO.class,
                            COLLECTION_NAME);                            

                }).switchIfEmpty(
                        Mono.defer(() -> {
                            return Mono.error(new Exception("User Name doesn't exist."));
                        })
                );
    }
```

For this, I have wriiten a testcase like this to test exception :

```
@Test
    public void DoAction_TestException() {
        SomeDTO someDTOObject = databaseUtil.SomeDTOMock;        

        Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("username").regex("^"+userId+"$","i"));
        doReturn(Mono.empty()).when(mongoTemplate).findOne(query,
                SomeDTO.class, "COLLECTION_NAME");
        try {
            SomeDTO someDTOObjectResult = mongoImpl.DoAction(someDTOObject).block();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            String expected = "User Name doesn't exist.";
            String result = e.getMessage().toString();   ///////  this value during debugging is "java.lang.Exception:User Name doesn't exist. "
            assertEquals(expected,result);
        }
       
    }
```

When I run the above code , the assert is failing becuase variable result has extra string along with it. How can I remove java.lang.Exception from the result ?
I dont want to use any string functions to remove part of string.ANy help would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eugene's answer is already showing you the correct way.

**Alternate Solution #1:**

Create a specific Exception class: `EntityNotFoundException extends IOException` or `UsernameNotFoundException extends IOException` and test if your result is an instance of that class.

**Alternate Solution #2:**

Extend your expected String *expected* to the String you really get.

**Alternate Solution #3:**

(I do not know Mono, so IF:) **If** Mono wraps up the Exception into another exception, you probably can reach that original exception by using `e.getCause`: Change your line `String result = e.getMessage().toString();` to `String result = e.getCause().getMessage();`.

To help us find that out, simply add the line `e.printStackTrace();` right after your line `String expected = "User Name doesn't exist.";`, and then show us what error message was printed. From there on we can help further, if the other solutions have not helped yet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was looking for this : String result = e.getCause().getMessage();

Answer (score 1):

If you're already in a catch clause, you're not dealing with Mono anymore.

In debugging you're checking `e.toString()`, which will be `"java.lang.Exception:User Name doesn't exist. "`.

But try to check behavior in a more isolated way.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exception exception = new Exception("User Name doesn't exist.");
        try {
            throw exception;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("getMessage: " +e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("toString: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

In this case e.getMessage() will print as expected `User Name doesn't exist.`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. As far I understand I'm checking e.getMessage() before asserting the values. like this ---> String result = e.getMessage().toString(); What do I need to change in this?