# Remove values from Set1 which are there in Set2 in java

Tags: java, hashset

I have a simple application which has 2 sets . I have to remove from Set1 based on the values from Set2.
Here is the code I have written :

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Users> cList = new HashSet<Users>();

        Users c = new Users();
        c.setUserId("modelId1");
        Set<String> cRoles = new HashSet();
        cRoles.add("USER");
        c.setRoles(cRoles);
        cList.add(c);

        c = new Users();
        c.setUserId("modelId2");
         cRoles = new HashSet();
        cRoles.add("ADMIN");
        c.setRoles(cRoles);
        cList.add(c);
   

        Set<Users> cList1 = new HashSet<Users>();

        c = new Users();
        c.setUserId("modelId1");
        cRoles = new HashSet();
        cRoles.add("ADMIN");
        c.setRoles(cRoles);
        cList1.add(c);  
  
        cList.removeAll(cList1.stream().filter(e -> cList.stream()
                .allMatch(p -> e.getUserId().equals(p.getUserId())))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()));

        System.out.println(cList.size());


    }
}
```

User class is as follows :

```
public class Users {
    private String userId;

    private Set<String> roles;


    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Set<String> getRoles() {
        return  roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(Set<String> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

My expectation is values from cList have to be removed which are there in cList1 based on the userid alone. If the userid matches , then the entire object needs to be removed from cList irrespective of roles.
The logic which I have written is not working as expected. Can anyone suggest what needs to be changed so that it works as I expected. Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Tried changing allMatch to anyMatch , but still not working .

```
cList.removeAll(cList1.stream().filter(e -> cList.stream()
                .anyMatch(p -> e.getUserId().equals(p.getUserId())))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Let your IDE generate Users.hashCode() and Users.equals() based on the User-ID only
2. Write `cList.removeAll(cList1);`

(maybe rename "Users" to "User", as this class/object represents only one user per instance)

Comment: There is another question of mine if you can please answer : https://stackoverflow.com/q/67383511/8930751

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the use of allMatch witch requires all the elements to have the user id searched for to be true. Instead use anyMatch witch will give the searched for behavior.

Comment: I changed it to anymatch , still it doesn't seem to work. cList still has modelId1 object , which is supposed to be removed. I have edited the question to show what I have changed.Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

@JayC667 is correct, that's the course of action I would take. Now if you can't make `Users.equals` and `Users.hashcode` based on `Users.userId`...

**Edit** The best solution in this case is to use `Collection.removeIf`:

```java
Set<String> removeIds = cList1.stream().map(Users::getUserId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
cList.removeIf(u -> removeIds.contains(u.getUserId()));
```

**End Edit:** *My previous ideas*

You can do this instead:

```java
Set<String> removeIds = cList1.stream().map(Users::getUserId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
Set<Users> remove = cList.stream().filter(
        u -> removeIds.contains(u.getUserId())
    ).collect(Collectors.toSet());
cList.removeAll(remove);
```

Or the all streams version (with performance concerns as you will stream cList1 multiple times):

```java
cList.removeAll(cList.stream().filter(
    u -> cList1.stream().map(Users::getUserId).anyMatch(id -> id == u.getUserId())
).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```